# Save http stream video android

Tags: android, video, stream, ffmpeg

For one of my android projects I need to implement saving of video from HTTP stream (right now I am just show live stream video to user).

I google that problem and find some solution, I can use FFmpeg. But FFmpeg is c++ library.

Is there are some easy way to save video from HTTP stream?